# How can the flap deflect to higher angles (than the wing) without experiencing loss of lift?

Tags: aerodynamics, flaps, angle-of-attack, cfd

For a simple aircraft wing, assume the stall angle of attack of this wing is 16 degrees. Now, if I use the same airfoil as used in the wing for the flaps, I am able to deflect the flap at quite greater angles. How is that possible? If I want to CFD analyze the flap geometry separately, can I use the maximum deflection of the flap as the angle of attack of incoming air in a CFD analysis? [Meaning will the CFD results obtained by isolating the flaps from the wings and conducting the analysis at an angle of attack the same as the maximum possible deflection of the flap, will be the same as when I conduct the analysis of the flaps together with the wing]?
How can I determine the maximum deflection of the flap? How to choose the best flap configuration for an aircraft? How determine the maximum possible deflection for the ailerons as well?

Comment: No, you can't analyse the flap geometry separately. It is not a separate element, it is moving part of the wing that allows changing its camber. And when you consider the actual chord as the leading edge moves with the slats and the trailing edge moves with the flaps, the critical angle of attack does not change much.
(I don't have much idea how to actually design a flap, so leaving this as comment only).

Comment: Would [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/52128/why-is-the-critical-aoa-of-most-flaps-40-when-most-airfoils-stall-at-15/52823#52823) help?

Comment: And even if you wanted to "analyze" the flap separately, the relative wind is altered by the wing it is attached to.